# How do I JSDoc @param in webstorm a callback handler's parameters?

Tags: javascript, webstorm, jsdoc

I am trying to use JSDoc hinting on the parameter of a handler but it doesn't work. I have tried with @type and @param and it does not work. The official JSDoc did not contain any helpful information regarding this problem.

This does not work:

```
    socket.on( "data",
    /**
     * @param request {Object}
     * @param request.code {Number}
     * @param request.id {Number}
     * @param request.sr {String}
     */
    function( request )
    {});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use complex "typedef" and "property" tags. Documented in: http://usejsdoc.org/tags-typedef.html
However, "~" char seems to prevent WebIde to link type annotations. (Just use plain typedef MyType annotation without tilde and it works)

BTW, for Google Closure way:

```
/** @typedef {{code: Number, id: Number, str: String}} **/
SocketRequest;

socket.on("data", handler);

/**
 * @param {SocketRequest} req
 */
function handler(req) {
    //req will be hinted here
}
```

This jsdoc annotation is especially for Google Closure, but can be used without Closure just for the sake of hinting.
(should work since August 2012: http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2012/08/closure-syntax/)

Answer (score 2):

I think you swapped the type and name of the objects, perhaps swapping them could help?

This is for jsdoc3, but I think it is the same:

http://usejsdoc.org/tags-param.html

Answer (score 1):

This is vague question, so here's my guess:

```
socket.on( "data",
/**
 * @param request {Object}
 * @param request.code {Number}
 * @param request.id {Number}
 * @param request.sr {String}
 */
function( request )
  typeof request.id == 'number';
  console.log(request.sr); // will print out the string
{});
```

The comment just describes which data / keys should be expected in the request object.

Comment: Yes and the comments don't work, it does not recognize neither code, nor sr. It doesn't even register as an Object.